# Writing a Finite state machine specification in Alloy

Tags: state-machine, alloy

I m new in alloy.
I am triying to make analog phone line specs in allow. Here is my FSM diagram.
[image: FSM visio diagram]

I have written a sample code to illustrate state transition.My transsition table is a fact, however output multiplicy is a problem in alloy syntax. I cant run this code.

Would you say me what is wrong. And any suggestion?

```
module state
sig Input{}
abstract sig State {
transition:  Input-> State-> Output}
one sig  NULL extends State {}
one sig CALL_RECEIVED extends State {}
fact xTable {
NULL->one setup_ind :Input->CALL_RECEIVED->one alerting_req:Output in transition
CALL_RECEIVED->one disconnect_ind:Input->NULL->one clear: Output in transition
}
pred show {}
run show
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using a made up syntax inside the `xTable` fact.  I suggest you look at http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation.html and learn the Alloy basics first.